# Access or get the id's of divs returned by php in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**DESCRIPTION :**

After some php work at the end,my php returns the following output to the jquery

```
<div id = "container1">
   <div id = "chicken1"></div>
   <div id = "soup1"></div>
</div>


<div id = "container2">
   <div id = "chicken2"></div>
   <div id = "soup2"></div>
</div>
```

and so on ...

Now in the jquery call back it gets lot of results. Now in jquery I want to get the id's of all the divs it recieved from the php. How can I do that.

Following Is The Code :

PHP

```
echo '<div id = "container1">
       <div id = "chicken1"></div>
       <div id = "soup1"></div>
    </div>


    <div id = "container2">
       <div id = "chicken2"></div>
       <div id = "soup2"></div>
    </div>';
```

JQUERY

```
$.post("../PHP/get_all_new_msgs_on_profile.php",{arr:data},function(result)
{
         //get the id's of the divs result has... 

});
```

Now the $(result) has the divs returned by the php how can I extract the id's of the divs from it ... PLease ignore any typing mistake . thanks :)

Comment: what did you tried, post that also.

Comment: Why don't you use classes?

Comment: Please explain **why** you want to do this, there is certainly a more logical solution

Comment: you want to get all IDs ? is that all?

Comment: @user574632 my php returns divs with the image and the message of the persons who sent you message .... I have a notification panel in which I have the recent received messages. Now if I have a message received from Aron I want the previously received message div replaced with the new one from Aron ... thats why

Comment: @UzumakiNaruto OK, well then i would suggest you return json data, eg `json_encode(array('name'=>'Aron','message'=>'hows it hangin?', 'image'=>'/path/to/image.jpg'));` then you can easily extract the data in js and put it in the dom. Its usually much easier to send data rather than markup via ajax, then handle the html in js

Comment: oohhhh yeaah yeaah i get it now ... I can do that ... Now I have two solutions nice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find all the div in html, iterate them, get the id's

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/a069tm2h/5/)

```
$(result).find('div').each(function(index){
console.log($(this).prop('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume your `result` variable holds the string

```
var result = '<div id = "container1"><div id = "chicken1"></div><div id = "soup1"></div></div><div id = "container2"><div id = "chicken2"></div>   <div id = "soup2"></div></div>';

var parser = new DOMParser();
var data = parser.parseFromString(result, "text/html");

var div = data.getElementsByTagName( 'div' );
var ids = [];

for( var i = 0; i < div.length; i++ ){
    ids.push( div[i].getAttribute('id') );
}
```

Array "ids" contains array of ids of the elements.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DrGeneral/z3au0cas/)

Answer (score 0):

To select element with partial attribute match use `div[id^="container"]`. To do so, you have to actually put that PHP output to DOM first, use function like `.append($data)`.

I think it's better to process data in PHP and return some structured data to jQuery callback (for example in JSON) and in js loop that data and wrap in some HTML.

```
[PHP]
echo json_encode(['itemId1' => ['someAttributes'], ...]);

[JS]
$.ajax({
   url: "../PHP/get_all_new_msgs_on_profile.php",
   dataType: 'json', // Will autoparse JSON!
   success: function(jsonArray){
       $.each(jsonArray, function(index, item){
           $('.parentWrapper').append(
               '<div id="container' + index + '" class="container">' + item.name + '</div>'
           );
       });

       $(document).on('click', '.container', function(){
          alert('Clicked on element');
       });

       //Do not use any return!
   }
});
```